# Using parallel iReport sub-reports

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have created a main report that contains 4 sub-reports in the same detail band.  These sub-reports are intended to display in parallel, but this is not what I am seeing.  What is happening is that the second sub-report starts when the first finishes, the third after the second, etc.  Also, if the length of a sub-report is longer than the page, it starts overwriting the first values from the top of the sub-report.  Has anyone experienced this with multiple sub-reports starting on the same row, and found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would try putting the parameter `position type` of the subreports to Float,  but not sure if it will work.